# MongoDB - Group by and count value, but treat per record as one

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregation-framework

I want to group by and count `follow_user.tags.tag_id` per record, so no matter how many times the same `tag_id` show up on the same record, it only counts as 1.

My database structure looks like this:

```
{ 
    "external_userid" : "EXID1", 
    "follow_user" : [
        {
            "userid" : "USERID1", 
            "tags" : [
                {
                    "tag_id" : "TAG1"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "userid" : "USERID2", 
            "tags" : [
                {
                    "tag_id" : "TAG1"
                },
                {
                    "tag_id" : "TAG2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{ 
    "external_userid" : "EXID2", 
    "follow_user" : [
        {
            "userid" : "USERID1", 
            "tags" : [
                {
                    "tag_id" : "TAG2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's my query:

```
[
  { "$unwind": "$follow_user" }, { "$unwind": "$follow_user.tags" },
  { "$group" : { "_id" : { "follow_user᎐tags᎐tag_id" : "$follow_user.tags.tag_id" }, "COUNT(_id)" : { "$sum" : 1 } } },
  { "$project" : { "total" : "$COUNT(_id)", "tagId" : "$_id.follow_user᎐tags᎐tag_id", "_id" : 0 } } 
]
```

What I expected:

```
{ 
    "total" : 1, 
    "tagId" : "TAG1"
},
{ 
    "total" : 2, 
    "tagId" : "TAG2"
}
```

What I get:

```
{ 
    "total" : 2, 
    "tagId" : "TAG1"
},
{ 
    "total" : 2, 
    "tagId" : "TAG2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `$set` - Create a new field `follow_user_tags`.

   1.1. [`$setUnion`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) - To distinct the value from the Result *1.1.1*.

   1.1.1. `$reduce` - Add the value of `follow_user.tags.tag_id` into array.
2. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `follow_user_tags` array field to multiple documents.
3. `$group` - Group by `follow_user_tags` and perform total count via `$sum`.
4. `$project` - Decorate output document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      follow_user_tags: {
        $setUnion: {
          "$reduce": {
            "input": "$follow_user.tags",
            "initialValue": [],
            "in": {
              "$concatArrays": [
                "$$value",
                "$$this.tag_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$follow_user_tags"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$follow_user_tags",
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      tagId: "$_id",
      total: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZRN0b3p5oH5)